# NSMutable Array beyond bounds

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray

I have a block of code which when executed gives me this error. And I am relatively new, I can't seem to fix the problem.

Error:
2011-09-06 12:31:06.094 ForceGauge[266:707] CoreAnimation: ignoring exception: *** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]

```
-(void)peakCollector:(NSMutableArray *)testarray {

    NSUInteger totalRows = [testarray count];

    NSMutableArray *percentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:0, nil];

    if(forcecontroller.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
        testarray = lbData;
    else if(forcecontroller.selectedSegmentIndex==1)
        testarray = kgData;     
    else if(forcecontroller.selectedSegmentIndex ==2)
        testarray = ozData;
    else if(forcecontroller.selectedSegmentIndex ==3)
        testarray = newtonData;

    for(int i = 0; i< totalRows-1; i++) {

        if ([[testarray objectAtIndex:i+1] doubleValue] >= 1.2 * [[testarray objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue]) {
            percentArray = [testarray objectAtIndex:i];

            DatabaseTable *tableVC = [[DatabaseTable alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:tableVC animated:YES];

            if(forcecontroller.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
                [tableVC copydatabase:percentArray];
            else if(forcecontroller.selectedSegmentIndex==1)
                [tableVC copydatabase:kgData];
            else if(forcecontroller.selectedSegmentIndex==2)
                [tableVC copydatabase:ozData];
            else if(forcecontroller.selectedSegmentIndex==3)
                [tableVC copydatabase:newtonData];

            [tableVC release];
        } else {
            [analogData removeAllObjects];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:0, nil];`. NSArray can only contain objects, not primitive types, you need to wrap them, e.g. `[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil];`

Comment: @Bavarious Still gives the same error.

Comment: @ila I have the impression the problem is somewhere else which is why I’ve deleted my answer. What I’d written (and albertamg posted as a comment) is still valid, though.

Comment: Even if the '0' value have indeed to be encapsulated in an NSNumber, the reason of the exception is elsewhere, hidden in a tricky typing problem: see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues here:

**1) NSArrays can only contains NSObjects.**

In your code, you are initializing your NSArray using `[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:0, nil];`, but 0 is an atomic type, not an NSObject
(and basically 0 is the same value as nil (nil and NULL are typically equal to 0, interpreted as the `id` and `void*` types, respectively)

You have to encapsulate your 0 value in an NSNumber instead :

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil];
```

Then retrieve the NSNumber using `[percentArray objectAtIndex:0]` and finally convert back the retrieve NSNumber to int using `NSNumber`'s `intValue` method:

```
NSNumber* number = [percentArray objectAtIndex:0]; // returns an NSNumber which is an NSObject encapsulating numbers, see Apple's documentation
int val = [number intValue]; // retrieve the integer value encapsulated in the NSNumber
// or directly:
// int val = [[percentArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
```

**2) The exception you got is in fact elsewhere and is much more subtle**: you are retrieving the `[testarray count]` value in an `NSUInteger` variable, which is an unsigned type. Then `totalRows-1` will do some tricky things if totalRows is equal to 0 (which is obviously the case considering the exception you have).

As `totalRows` is an `NSUInteger`, when it is equal to 0, `totalRows-1` will not be equal to -1, but to... `(NSUInteger)-1` (-1 interpreted as an unsigned integer), which is 0xFFFFFFFF, or namely the maximum value of the `NSUInteger` type!

This is why `i` is always less than this `totalRows-1` value (as this value is not -1 but **0xFFFFFFFF = NSUInteger_MAX**).

To solve this issue, cast your `totalRows` variable to an NSInteger value, or add a condition in your code to treat this special case separately.

Comment: I fixed the NSUInteger and it got rid of the error. Now I have other problems, what I know is that it's not going beyond the loop now.

Comment: Glad I solve your problem then (as it was kinda tricky to see!) :)

Comment: ilaunchpad, you should check the answer box for AliSoftware's answer to give him the credit.

Comment: @AliSoftWare Would you be able to complete the number 1 task? I always get confused in NSNumber matters.                                  NSMutableArray *percentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0, nil]];

Comment: Hi I don't understand your comment: the extract of code I posted about the NSNumber thing in my above answer is not clear enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the how many objects test array contains at beginning of for loop.

Other thing that can help is that avoid NSUInteger and use simple int for storing array count.

Please post if this don't work.

Answer (score 0):

The error simply means that you're trying to retrieve an object at an index that does not exist. In your specific case, the array you're trying to get the object from does not have an object at index 1

An easy example

```
[0] => MyCoolObject
[1] => MySecondObject
[2] => ObjectTheThird
```

You can access indexes 0,1,2 of your array as they contain objects. If you now would try to access index 3 it would throw the `Out of bounds` exception as index 3 does not exist.